# Populate a multilevel Map using a for loop

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, for-loop, hashmap

I'm trying to add Map<String, dynamic> as values for integer keys within Map<**int**, Map> while a for loop is used to iterate the **int**. However, I'm getting the following error:

> Unhandled exception:
>
> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
>
> #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
>
> #1      main (file:///X:/test/commands.dart:....)
>
> <asynchronous suspension>

Below is the code used. I have tried with List<Map> as well, but the error persists.

Expected result:

```
 service = { 

              0: { 'serviceName': value, 'departure': value }

           }
```

Can anyone please point out the problem here?

```
var trips = document.getElementsByClassName('searchresults')[0].getElementsByClassName('trip');

print(trips.length); // =379

var tripCount = trips.length;

print(trips[1].getElementsByClassName('schedule')[0].text.trim()); //serviceName as String

Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>> services = {};

for (int i = 0; i < tripCount; i++) {
    services[i] = { 
        'serviceName': trips[i].getElementsByClassName('schedule')[0].text.trim(), 
        'departure': trips[i].getElementsByClassName('departure')[0].text.trim()
    }; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this on dartpad and worked fine   Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>> services = {};

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    services[i] = { 
        'serviceName': "text", 
        'departure': "text"
    }; 
    
}
    print(services);

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if service name and departure are actually accessible where you're trying to access them using index 0. For example here:

```dart
'serviceName': trips[i].getElementsByClassName('schedule')[0].text.trim(), 
'departure': trips[i].getElementsByClassName('departure')[0].text.trim()
```

Comment: It works fine while printing. I had included the line in the code : ```print(trips[1].getElementsByClassName('schedule')[0].text.trim())``` - gives a string.

Comment: I think the problem came down to "value range empty" issue at index, i=9. I tested only the initial indexes and it worked fine. Moreover, the HTML also looked uniform.